# How to run for president of the United States with time machine?

Tags: alternate-history, government, time-travel

A mad scientist was murdered and his invention was stolen, it is a disposable time machine which can instantaneously allow any person to swap minds flawlessly and painlessly with anybody from the past. How can the user used such device to become a president? There are countless of timelines spontaneously being created and one of them must be where the user becoming the world leader, the targeted person must not be already or going to be a president himself or participate in any presidential elections. After the swapping both parties will have no recollection of each other memories.

Comment: "must not be already or going to be a president himself or participate in any *presidential* elections" - but can they still be a politician, e.g. a senator or governor who just needs a little extra push, or can they not have participated in politics at all?

Comment: @colmde: those directly involved in past presidential elections/campaigns excluding voters do not qualify.

Comment: yes but my question is about non-presidential elections, e.g. elections for senate, mayor, governor, etc.

Comment: @colmde: they're eligible!

Comment: This seems Too Broad to me.  Clearly the time traveler needs to pick someone who has the resources to become President and then execute a plan.  Any number of people might fit this description.  For example, Colin Powell, Michelle Obama, Condoleeza Rice, Warren Buffet, and James Mattis deliberately chose not to run for President.  Or pick an obscure state legislator in 2004 and have that person run for Senate (Obama).  There are too many people and too many options by which they could run.  And this seems a bit contrived.  Why not just pick a President and make better decisions?

Comment: What about assassinated/murdered potential candidates? You could avoid the thing that killed them, and then run as they probably would have.

Answer (score 2):

"How can the user used such device to become a president?"

Travel in time and swap minds?

But if your question is "when and where would be ideal opportunity to do such thing" then you have two options:

1. choose time in target life when his personality change would not be noticed or explained by some external stimuli (maybe war, military training, long vacation in Himalayan)
2. you have time machine so acting in linear manner don't apply to you. You can travel in time to any period, change/influence targets life, jump to another time do the same to somebody else, jump back to first target 10 years later, change/influence his life again and so on and so on.

The second one is more efficient if you have a greater scheme in mind (like, I don't know, starting turmoil in middle east in 1980's to start World War III 40 years later) and less time consuming. You need few days of your life to alter  somebody else life instead of sacrificing few years to fully impersonate candidate.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm going to do this the hard way.

Pick a person you want to be president, anyone as long as they're eligible, it doesn't matter. Pick yourself if you like.

Standing for one of the big parties saves time later, but you can go independent, it'll just take longer. If you pick a worthwhile candidate to start with it'll be an easier ride once you're into the system.

Now spend the rest of your life swapping bodies with voters to elect your candidate. There's no point being subtle, just work your way down the opposition voting lists first, then start on the unaligned. At some point you'll have done enough to elect your president.

Comment: Oh my unfortunately the user had to used up the only time machine which only works between the user and anyone from the past... meaning you can't recycle nor reuse this device.

Comment: That's... that's actually easier way. You don't even have to start a campaign. Just swap minds with every voter, jump back and forth 10-20 minutes so you can cast a vote and select whatever you want as a write-in.

Comment: @user6760, that's easily solved, pick someone close to the inventor, go back and convince him to lay in facilities to mass produce them before stealing the whole production run. Time machine remember.